# Procmail: Send mails per default to deliver

Tags: 16.04, server, postfix, dovecot

i have a question^^:

First i show you an simple procmail rule:

```
DELIVER="/usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -d $LOGNAME"
DEFAULT="$HOME/Maildir/"
MAILDIR="$HOME/Maildir/"
# deliver spam to spam folder
:0 w
* ^X-Spam-Status: Yes
| $DELIVER -m Spam

# deliver to INBOX and stop
:0 w
| $DELIVER
```

Now my question, is there a way to use DELIVER as Default like:

```
DEFAULT="/usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -d $LOGNAME"
```

So that all mails goes to dovecot after the procmail rules are checked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to specify a pipe (or forwarding to another address) as the default delivery destination in Procmail. Basically, the best you can do is to add this unconditional recipe to the very and of your `.procmailrc`, like you are already doing.

```
:0w
| /usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -d "$LOGNAME"
```

Incidentally, storing a command with parameters in a string variable is rather brittle, and is hard or impossible to do correctly when you need to quote some arguments. Procmail inherits this problem, and the syntax, from the shell; perhaps see further https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

A possible variation is to only set a variable to indicate the destination in your recipes, and only deliver at the very end. Perhaps like this:

```
:0
* ^From sender-gossip-l@listserv\.example\.net
{ dest="Gossip" }

:0E
* ^From: majordomo@example\.edu
* ^Subject: \[fnord\]
{ dest="Fnord" }

:0E
... etc

:0w
| /usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -d "$LOGNAME" ${dest+-m "$dest"}
```

Meticulously using an `E` flag on every recipe after the first one means the first one whose conditions match wins, like in a regular Procmail recipe file; without it, the *last* matching recipe wins, and you will always process all recipes.

Comment: thank you for your reply and this note about my "function variables". i was afraid that the default variable cannot really be manipulated.. I guess we should switch to herve after all ^^ :D

thank you